# Return 307 Temporary Redirect in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, redirect, http-status-code-307

Is it possible to return a `307 Temporary Redirect` from a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

I *sometimes* need to re-`POST` the values submitted from one form to another URI.

Using JavaScript to do the selection on the client side (thereby bypassing this issue) is not an option.

Redirecting via a `GET` is not an option as posted data includes an 8k string which is likely to mean that the URI would be too long for some (many?) browsers.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following article - you can use the same technique for 307:

[301 Redirects](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx)

Comment: I need to *sometimes* make the redirects based on the data that's passed.  Accessing the model (where the logic is) from the routehandler seems wrong.  Having [a copy of] the logic in the routehandler seems even worse.

Comment: Using a RouteHandler seems like a nice way to solve this kind of problem though. - Just not when there's logic involved.

Comment: You could create a different action result in which case - again here's an example that you can modify:

http://www.stum.de/2008/10/22/permanentredirectresult/

Comment: I've ended up doing some redesign to avoid this whole issue. Some great solutions though. Thanks FinnNk

Comment: Breaks the requirement "sometime" which implies logic is required first. Not bad as a general purpose solution but doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 16):

To return a 307 redirect result from an MVC action, use the following:

```
public ActionResult Action()
{
    string url = GetRedirectUrl()
    HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Location", url);
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(307);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirectresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RedirectResult__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_):

```
 public RedirectResult (string url, bool permanent, bool preserveMethod);
```

So

```
return Redirect(url, false, false); // 302
return Redirect(url, true, false);  // 301
return Redirect(url, false, true);  // 307
return Redirect(url, true, true);   // 308
```