# Do an HTTP 307 redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

For technical reasons we need to perform an HTTP 307 redirect instead of a 302.

For 302's I'd do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url)
```

For 301's I do:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(url)
```

How would I implement a 307?

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644045/return-307-temporary-redirect-in-asp-net-mvc can help

Comment: @gidanmx2 am using webforms, can't seem to get any of the examples to work (tried setting status code to 307 and adding location header)

Comment: Did you look up how to manually set the status code of a response, set headers, and end the response? Should be pretty easy to find documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding a location header and doing redirect manually:

```
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 307;
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusDescription = "Temporary Redirect";
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectURL);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page you want to cause a 307, instead of Response.Redirect use Server.Transfer: -

```
Server.Transfer("targetpage.aspx");
```

Then in Page_Load of your target page, add the following (smiley face optional): -

```
Response.StatusCode = 307;
Response.StatusDescription = "Temporary Redirect :)";
```

When you view the network trace in your browser's debug tools, this will look like the source page returned a 307. `Server.Transfer` does not send a response to the browser, but instead immediately transfers control to the specified page.